# Using $.ajax post to send data to node.js server not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, body-parser

My goal is to convert a table date into array and send the array to the server side using Ajax post. This is my first time using Ajax post and i have followed all the answer in previous post. I don't still know what am missing. I am using body-parser to get the data on the server side. I will appreciate any assistance or **if there is another easier way to send array to server side**. My current output in undefined when I tried to print the output. Please see my code below:

**ejs side**

```
<table id="cartGrid">
        <thead>
             <tr>
                <th>Item Description</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Unit Price</th>
                <th>Ext Price</th>
             </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr><td>Old Lamp</td><td>1</td><td>107.00</td><td>107.00</td>
          <tr><td>Blue POst</td><td>2</td><td>7.00</td><td>14.00</td>
   </tbody>
</table>

<script>
// convert table to array

    var myTableArray = [];
    $("table#cartGrid tr").each(function() { 
    var arrayOfThisRow = [];
    var tableData = $(this).find('td');
    if (tableData.length > 0) {
        tableData.each(function() { arrayOfThisRow.push($(this).text()); });
        myTableArray.push(arrayOfThisRow);
    }

// post the data
$.ajax({
        url: "/saler",
        type: "POST",
        data: myTableArray,
    });

});

</script>
```

**server side**

```
router.post('/saler', function (req, res, next) {
  var myTableArray = req.body.myTableArray;
  console.log(myTableArray);
});
```

**app.js**

```
app.use( bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no `myTableArray` in your request body.

unless when you sending data you do this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/saler",
        type: "POST",
        data: {myTableArray},
    });

});
```

then you can do `req.body.myTableArray` to read the `myTableArray`.

try `console.log(req.body)` first to check the data struct in your request.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I have an issue of the post working immediately when I load the page. Please how can I prevent this? I prefer it to only work when I click a button. Thanks.

Comment: @NaheemOlaniyan add a button in your page. add click event listener to it, `<button onclick=postMethod>Send</button>`. `postMethod` is where you call `$.ajax`

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much.